# Почему метод не содержит информации о типе последователь­ности?

Tags: java, коллекции

Читаю Брюса Эккеля "Философия Java", стр. 338

> В качестве другого примера рассмотрим создание метода вывода
> содержимого, не за­висящего от контейнера:
>
> ```
> //: holding/CrossContainerIteration.java
> import typeinfo.pets.*j
> import java.util.*j
> public class CrossContainerIteration {
>
> public static void display(Iterator<Pet> it) {
> while(it.hasNext()) {
>  Pet p = it.next();
>  System.out.print(p.id() + ":" + p + " ");
> }
> System.out.println();
> }
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>   ArrayList<Pet> pets = Pets.arrayList(8);
>   LinkedList<Pet> petsLL = new LinkedList<Pet>(pets);
>   HashSet<Pet> petsHS = new HashSet<Pet>(pets);
>   TreeSet<Pet> petsTS = new TreeSet<Pet>(pets);
>   display(pets.iterator());
>   display(petsLL.iterator());
>   display(petsHS.iterator());
>   display(petsTS.iterator());
> }
>
> } 
>
> /* Output:
> 0:Rat l:Manx 2:Cymric 3:Mutt 4:Pug 5:Cymric 6:Pug 7:Manx
> 0:Rat l:Manx 2:Cymric 3:Mutt 4:Pug 5:Cymric 6:Pug 7:Manx
> 4:Pug 6:Pug 3:Mutt l:Manx 5:Cymric 7:Manx 2:Cymric 0:Rat
> 5:Cymric 2:Cymric 7:Manx l:Manx 3:Mutt 6:Pug 4:Pug 0:Rat
> *///:~
> ```
>
> Обратите внимание: метод display() не содержит информации о типе
> последователь­ности.

Почему автор говорит что `display` не содержит информации о типе последователь­
ности, ведь в самом входящем аргументе метода задан тип `display(Iterator<Pet> it)` ? Да и внутри метода указано `Pet p`

Comment: В коде указан тип данных в последовательности, но не сам тип контейнера. Им может быть как, например, ArrayList, так и LinkedList.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб но тогда надо было писать "метод display() не содержит информации о типе контейнера."? А не как сейчас написано "метод display() не содержит информации о типе последователь­ности."

Comment: Считаю, что в данном случае можно и слово контейнер применить и последовательность. Важно, что тут 2 типа есть - тип коллекции/списка/последовательности/контейнера и данных, содержащихся в коллекции/списке/последовательности/контейнере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Эккеля эти понятия синонимичны: `List` называется и контейнером последовательности:

> *the library has different types of containers for different needs: several different kinds of `List` classes (to hold sequences)*

и последовательностью:

> *different containers have different efficiencies for certain operations. For example, there are two basic types of List: `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. Both are simple sequences that can have identical interfaces and external behaviors*

источник: [Bruce Eckel, *Thinking in Java* 4th Edition, Dec 2007](http://www.dblab.ntua.gr/%7Egtsat/collection/Java%20books/Bruce.Eckel.Thinking.In.Java.4th.Edition.Dec.2007.eBook-BBL.pdf)

В данном примере типизированный итератор `Iterator<Pet>` позволяет абстрагироваться и от типа контейнера/коллекции (Set / List), и от конкретной реализации этих контейнеров / вида последовательности (`HashSet / TreeSet` или `ArrayList / LinkedList`).